# Вывод текста в TextView

Tags: android, textview

Как вывести в `TextView` номер телефона, `URL` и `email`, чтобы по клику открывалась либо почта, либо браузер, либо вызов введенного номера.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернатива можно указать в XML разметке атрибут `autoLink`:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/myText"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:autoLink="all"
/>
```